# delete from json conditionally

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have some JSON that looks like this

```
var js = '{
            "person" : {
                        "firstname" : "Steve",
                        "lastname" : "Smith",
                        "other": [
                                    { 
                                       "age" : "32",
                                       "deceased" : false
                                    },
                                    { 
                                       "age" : "14",
                                       "deceased" : false
                                    },
                                    { 
                                       "age" : "421",
                                       "deceased" : false
                                    }
                                 ]
                       }
         }'
```

I know how I delete all of "other" by doing this

```
var j = JSON.parse(js)
delete j[person.other]
```

but what I really want is to delete the "other" node with a condition that is age = 14.

The result JSON I am looking for is

```
{
            "person" : {
                        "firstname" : "Steve",
                        "lastname" : "Smith",
                        "other": [
                                    { 
                                       "age" : "32",
                                       "deceased" : false
                                    },
                                    { 
                                       "age" : "421",
                                       "deceased" : false
                                    }
                                 ]
                       }
}
```

I have looked at the delete operator [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) and it does not provide a conditional.

Sorry if this is too simple a question. I am learning.

Thanks

Comment: `person.other` is an `Array` -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to filter object array based on attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722159/how-to-filter-object-array-based-on-attributes)

Comment: You don't want to `delete` the whole array. You want to [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the existing array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach to this would be not to alter the json, but create another one instead:

```js
const filtered = { ...json, other: json.other.filter(item => item.age !== "14") }
```

If you really need to alter the json, you can do the following:

```js
let index = json.other.findIndex(item => item.age === "14")
while (index !== -1) {
  json.other.splice(index, 1)
  index = json.other.findIndex(item => item.age === "14")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a filter on the array doing something like

```
j[person.other].filter(x => x.age != 14)
```

Doc on how filter works more in depth here :

https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter